# calling asmx service using jquery ajax asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asmx

I'm trying to call a sample asmx service using jquery, here is the jquery code

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Services/Tasks.asmx/HelloWorld",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {                   
                alert(data);                    
            }
        });
```

This is not showing any message,code is in asp.net 4.0, 
Am I missing any thing?

Edit - I changed the dataType to xml, now success function is working it return following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Hello World</string>
```

I'm using following code to parse xml data and it is showing null in alert

```
success: function (data) {
    edata = $(data).find("string").html();
    alert(data);
}
```

Comment: try adding complete: function(x,y,z){ } and see what's returned

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it's because you have the dataType: "json" and it's expecting the response content-type to be the same but XML is being returned. I bet the complete event is being raised but not success.

try

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Services/Tasks.asmx/HelloWorld",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {                   
                alert(data);                    
            },
            complete: function (data) {                   
                alert(data);                    
            }
        });
```

### UPDATE

I think it's because you're using .html(), you need to use text(). Also i don't know if you meant to do it or not but you have `data` in your alert, i'm assuming you meant to use `edata`. The following worked for me:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/yourURL",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data) {
        edata = $(data).find("string").text();
        alert(edata);
    }
})
```

Comment: u got it, in complete event i'm trying to parse xml as "edata = $(data).find("string").html();" it is returning null.

Comment: i set datatype as xml, now success works, but now error is in xml parsing

Comment: you get an error parsing the XML? what are you using to parse the XML? Maybe update your question to include the response XML so we can test it.

Comment: Thanks buddy, using text() instead of html resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend adding the [ScriptService] attribute to your Tasks.asmx class so it will accept and respond in JSON instead of XML. Your client code looks good, but you'll want to take a look at "data.d" instead of "data" in your success handler.

Answer (score 2):

```
  use it.

   <script>
        alert("aaa");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "MyService.asmx/HelloWorld",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "xml",
        contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
        alert(data);//data-object xmldocument
        edata = $(data).children("string").text();
        alert(edata);

        }
    });
    alert("bbb");
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're stating that the dataType is JSON, but the contentType is XML. Try

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

If not, then we'd have to see the asmx code.