# PageMethods and UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel, pagemethods

I have a page hierarchy as the following

[image]

I want to execute a PageMethod if I click the 'SAVE' button, so I coded like the following

#### On Button Click I called

```
OnClientClick="return btnSaveAS_Clicked()"
```

#### Called the following on PageLoad of the inner user control

```
private void RegisterJavaScript()
{
    StringBuilder jScript = new StringBuilder();
    jScript.Append("<script type='text/javascript'>");
    jScript.Append(@"function btnSaveAS_Clicked() {
        var txtConditionName = document.getElementById('" + txtConditionName.ClientID + @"').value;
        PageMethods.Combine('hello','world', OnSuccess);
        function onSuccess(result)
        {
            alert(result);
        }
    }");
    jScript.Append("</script>");

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "conditions_key", jScript.ToString());
}
```

#### Coded page method as

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Combine(string s1, string s2) {
  return s1 + "," + s2;
}
```

But it gives the following error...

[image]

Comment: So where does the UpdatePanel factor in here?

Comment: @jcolebrand : Update panel is in the 'Page'. In the 'Page', I have a dropdownlist, based on the selection I will load user controls.

Comment: where is the Page method ? Page or in UserControl ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot define page methods in ascx pages. You have to define them in your web form. If you want to have a page method, defined in your user control, you'd have to define a *forwarding page method* in you aspx page like below ([source](http://blogs.iis.net/rakkimk/archive/2008/03/20/ajax-calling-pagemethods-defined-on-a-usercontrol.aspx)):

in user control:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public static string MyUserControlPageMethod()
{
    return "Hello from MyUserControlPageMethod";
}
```

in aspx.cs page:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public static string ForwardingToUserControlMethod()
{
    return WebUserControl.MyUserControlMethod();
}
```

and in aspx page:

```
 function CallUserControlPageMethod()
 {
     PageMethods.ForwardingToUserControlPageMethod(callbackFunction);           
 }
```

Alternatively, you could use ASMX services and `jquery` ajax methods ([jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)) to call your methods asynchronously ([sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808641/calling-asmx-service-using-jquery-ajax-asp-net-4-0)).

Another option would be defining http handlers and call them via jQuery as well ([tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/170882/jQuery-AJAX-and-HttpHandlers-in-ASP-NET)).

Comment: Oh snap, I totally missed that that was defined in the .ascx, good job. Alternately, he could use an ASMX instead to host the webmethod.

Comment: good point. defining http handler and calling it via jquery.ajax is my best practice.

Comment: @Kamyar ,  : If I use 'forwarding page method', will it degrade the performance ?

Comment: @jcolebrand ,  : If I use 'forwarding page method', will it degrade the performance ?

Comment: @mraufk: depends on how you define `performance degrading`. But in general I don't think it's going to cause any considerable performance issue. the overhead is completely ignorable in most cases since it's on the server side, not the client side.

Comment: @Kamyar : Well. Then if I need to pass a text box's value(its in InnerUserControl) from the Page,should I write public property or .. ?

Comment: you can pass it as a parameter of your method. and fill the parameter with the appropriate value in your client-side call.

Comment: @Kamyar let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1824/discussion-between-rauf-nicole-and-kamyar)

Comment: @Kamyar that is OK. but i failed to get the following return WebUserControl.MyUserControlMethod(ddlValue);
How can I access the user control inside a static method ?

Comment: you can't. you have to pass the value from the client side using <%= %> markup.